# installer created with install4j for mac os not showing custom icon

Tags: macos, icons, install4j

I have created an two installer of java application using install4j.
One for Windows system and one for Mac OS X.

Setup.exe file of windows installer have custom icon which I have given but mac os installer don't have icon which is provided by me even when installing application desktop shortcut also don't have the icon.

So, Can you please help me how to use custom icon for mac application installer.

My file is a png file of 32x32.

In window it is working perfectly but for mac it is not showing my icon on desktop shortcut as well as on application icon.

Am I need to give image with any specific size for mac ?

Please help me setting icon for mac.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add icons sizes 16x16, 32x32, 64x64 and 128x128 for optimal performance.

The desktop link icon will come from the icon that has been set for the launcher, not for the installer. install4j will generate ICNS icon files from these images. Alternatively, you can specify your own ICNS files in all icon configurations.

Comment: My install4j failed to generate ICNS from a set of the png icons with sizes you suggested above. A better solution could be to give it ICO and ICNS files directly, perhaps?

Comment: That should not happen. What was the error message?

Comment: It seems that the version I have can only generate an icon from cross-platform image files for Windows. For Mac it only has 2 options - use standard icon (blank app icon) or specify ICNS file. The version is 5.1, and that's what I had the licence for. Probably newer versions can actually create Mac icons too, I don't know.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Cross-platform ICNS generation was added in 6.0.